# solution or workarounds for haskell-src-exts parsing modules with CPP failing

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to do some parsing of a bunch of haskell source files using `haskell-src-exts` but ran into trouble in the first file I tested on. Here is the first bit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP, MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -fno-warn-orphans #-}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- |
-- Module      :  FRP.Reactive.Fun
-- Copyright   :  (c) Conal Elliott 2007
-- License     :  GNU AGPLv3 (see COPYING)
-- 
-- Maintainer  :  conal@conal.net
-- Stability   :  experimental
-- 
-- Functions, with constant functions optimized, with instances for many
-- standard classes.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

module FRP.Reactive.Fun (Fun, fun, apply, batch) where

import Prelude hiding
  ( zip, zipWith
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 609
                , (.), id
#endif
  )
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 609
import Control.Category
#endif
```

And the code I'm using to test:

```
*Search> f <- parseFile "/tmp/file.hs"
*Search> f
ParseFailed (SrcLoc {srcFilename = "/tmp/file.hs", srcLine = 19, srcColumn = 1}) "Parse error: ;"
```

The issue appears to be the CPP conditional sections, but it appears that CPP is a [supported extenstion](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.11.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Extension.html#t%3aExtension). I'm using `haskell-src-exts-1.11.1` with ghc 7.0.4

I'm just trying to do some quick and dirty analysis, so I don't mind stripping out those sections before parsing if I have to, but better solutions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly use [cpphs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpphs) to "evaluate" the pre-processor statements first?

Also, that is the known extension list copied (and extended) from *Cabal*; haskell-src-exts [doesn't support](http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-src-exts/ticket/27) CPP.

Comment: ahh, I guess I could have read the docs I linked to. And I did see that bug report, but misunderstood that the bug was resolved in 1.9.x.    Can you tell me why haskell-src-exts depends on `cpphs` (I'm not curious enough to look through the code)?

Comment: @jberryman it uses cpphs' `Language.Preprocessor.Unlit` module to read in Literate Haskell source.