# Error parsing haskell source file containing # (c preprocessor)

Tags: haskell, preprocessor

When parsing haskell source files that contain `#define` and `#if`, `parseFileContentsWithMode` gets confused and throws an error about the hash. I tried to include `MagicHash` and `CPP` in the extension list (`extns`, see below) but that didn't work. I can't really change the source files because there are a lot of them.

```
getModule extns filePath program = fromParseResult $ parseFileContentsWithMode mode program
                         where
                                  bangPatternsExt = map parseExtension extns
                                  mode = ParseMode filePath Haskell2010 bangPatternsExt False False
```

The parser failed at:

```
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 612

instance Lift ModName where
  lift = lift . modString
```

Comment: If it's `#define` and similar that's causing you problems, you don't want `MagicHash`, you want `CPP`.

Comment: I tried only adding that also, didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell-src-exts doesn't support CPP natively (there is no issue in the GitHub issue tracker for that, but an old one on trac at http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-src-exts/ticket/27).

You can look at [solution or workarounds for haskell-src-exts parsing modules with CPP failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235688/solution-or-workarounds-for-haskell-src-exts-parsing-modules-with-cpp-failing) for workarounds (using cpphs).

There is also a package called hse-cpp (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hse-cpp) that looks like it can run cpphs for you, but I haven't used it, and it doesn't seem to get updated a lot.